# Installation of libFFM in Ubuntu 15.04

Tags: ubuntu

I am trying to use libFFM in my system using Ubuntu 15.04. I followed the installation step as given in the github page: https://github.com/guestwalk/libffm. After the make command I do see two executables ffm-train and ffm-predict in my master folder, but when I type

```
ffm-train bigdata.tr.txt model
```

it says 'ffm-train:command not found'.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Enter the folder containing the binary, type "ff" and press tab a few times. This should show you everything starting with "ff" in that folder or write out the entire name of the binary for you if it's the only thing in the folder starting with "ff".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An old question but I found little existing help elsewhere. Hopefully this might help other future users. I raised a bug on github and guestwalk [replied](https://github.com/guestwalk/libffm/issues/3#issuecomment-239518694). When in the libffm directory using the following worked.

```
./ffm-train bigdata.tr.txt model
```